# Having issues on flutter

Tags: flutter

android {
compileSdkVersion 33
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

added the 33 and this is the output :

/C:/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Hello there, you need to change the `compileSdkVersion` at `android/app/build.gradle` to 33.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `compileSdkVersion` in the `build.gradle` file of the **application** scope of android app(by default it's on 29 line)

```
path_to_your_project/android/app/build.gradle
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

debug console already show you the solution of your error you just need to read and understand your error and the solution will be in front of you